# Sending private message to user with socket.io

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am trying to implement private messaging with socket.io for my mobile applications which have a direct messaging feature like Instagram. Right now, I am using Node.js and React Native. I am kinda new to socket.io. I saw many examples of that. However, one thing is not clear in my mind.
User clicks "send message" button. Then I create a socket connection and the user joins a room with socket id. Then user sends a message to that room.
The problem here is, how other user will get the message? Because at this point, I don't think other user knows the room id. Of course if there is a better solution for that, I am open to every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a room for each person. When the person logs into your app and connects with socket.io, you'll want to have them automatically join the room with their user id.

Then when someone wants to send them a message, they can just send the message to the room for the receiving user.

However, I think if you are building a messaging app, socket.io is not the right way to go. As far as I know you can't listen on sockets while the app is in the background (and even if you could, it would drain your users' battery life). You should use push notifications instead and use the data field (e.g. zo0r/react-native-push-notification and firebase).

Comment: You are right about push notifications. I am planning to use push notifications if user is not using the app. But for live chat, like Instagram, I thought socket.io is gonna be good way to go. At least for starting. One question in my mind is that how should I hold rooms data? Should I create a variable called "rooms"? I just wanna know the best practice of those kind of jobs.

Comment: By my expierince socket.io isnt the right solution when we need "one on one" chat.I spent months on that topic and i failed to implement private messages with socket.io.